# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode, load, python-unicode

I'm trying to load a csv file using `pd.read_csv` but I get the following unicode error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Could you share your code. That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: It's just `pd.read_csv('../filename.csv')` and then I get that unicode error. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, CSV files have no built-in method of signalling character encoding.

`read_csv` defaults to guessing that the bytes in the CSV file represent text encoded in the UTF-8 encoding. This results in `UnicodeDecodeError` if the file is using some other encoding that results in bytes that don't happen to be a valid UTF-8 sequence. (If they by luck did also happen to be valid UTF-8, you wouldn't get the error, but you'd still get wrong input for non-ASCII characters, which would be worse really.)

It's up to you to specify what encoding is in play, which requires some knowledge (or guessing) of where it came from. For example if it came from MS Excel on a western install of Windows, it would probably be Windows code page 1252 and you could read it with:

```
pd.read_csv('../filename.csv', encoding='cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position
>   51: invalid continuation byte

This was because I made changes to the file and its encoding. You could also try to change the encoding of file to utf-8 using some code or nqq editor in ubuntu as it provides directory option to change encoding. If problem remains then try to undo all the changes made to the file or change the directory.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code, open a new .py file and enter code and save.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue recently. This was what I did
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).